# CXF jar conflict with spring jar version.?

Tags: java, spring, cxf

Previously I was used spring 4.1.6 version and  cxf relation jar version is 2.6.1.
Now I have change spring version to 4.3.30 which is not compatible with cxf version 2.6.1 jars.

Because of this I am getting error like **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory**

What is exact cxf version for spring 4.3.30 version?

Answer (score 0):

I just download the jar from maven central

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs/2.6.1
```

And from what I see in the packages it has ProviderFactory in that exact place, are you positive that you have this jar as a dependency and if you do have you pulled dependencies if you are using maven or any other building tool?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try spring version 4.3.30 with cxf version 3.2.14.

According to the mvn repository pages below, cxf version 3.2.14 is compatible with spring boot version 1.5.22 (spring version 4.3.25).

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws/3.2.14
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.5.22.RELEASE